# Adding data to an already existing partition in Postgres using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to parition a table on 2 columns, and insert records to an already **existing** partition of a Postgres table using Python (Psycopg2).

I am very new to Python and Postgres, hence struggling a bit with a challenging requirement. I searched the internet and found that Postgres does not support `Partitioning by List` on multiple columns.

I have 2 tables - "cust_details_curr" & "cust_details_hist". Both the tables will have the same structure. However the "_hist" table needs to be partitioned on 2 columns - 'area_code' and 'eff_date'

```
CREATE TABLE cust_details_curr
(
 cust_id int,
 area_code varchar(5),
 cust_name varchar(20),
 cust_age int
 eff_date date
);

CREATE TABLE cust_details_hist
(
 cust_id int,
 area_code varchar(5),
 cust_name varchar(20),
 cust_age int
 eff_date date
); -- Needs to be partitioned on area_code and eff_date
```

- The "area_code" is passed as an argument to the process.
- The column "eff_date" is supposed to contain the current process run
  date.

There are multiple "area_codes" to be passed as an argument to the program - (there are 5 values - A501, A502, A503, A504, X101) all of which will run **sequentially** on the same day (i.e eff_date will be the same for all the runs).

The requirement is that whenever the "curr" table is being loaded for a specific "area_code", the program must first copy the data already existing in the "curr" table (for that specific area_code) into a partition of "eff_date" and that specific "area_code" of the "_hist" table. Next, the data pertaining to the same area_code in "curr" table must be deleted, and new data for that area_code will be loaded with the current process date in the eff_date column.

However, the process should run for 1 area_code at a time and hence the process will run for multiple area_codes on the same day. (which means they will all have eff_date = same current date)

So my question is -

- how to partition the _hist table by 2 columns - area_code and
  eff_date ?
- Also, once a partition of the eff_date is created (assume 2022-08-01)
  and loaded in the _hist table for one of the area_codes (assume
  A501), the next job in the sequence will need to load the data for
  another area_code (say A502) to load into the same eff_date partition
  (since eff_date is same for both the process instances as they are
  executed on the same day ) How can I insert data into the existing
  partition ?

I devised the following (crude) way to handle the requirement when it was only for a single partition column - "eff_date". For that I would execute the sql queries below in order to somewhat implement the initial requirements for a single eff_date and area_code value.

However, I am struggling to figure out how to implement the same with multiple area_codes as a second partition column in the _hist table, And how to insert data into an already existing date partition (eff_dt), loaded by a previous area_code instance.

```
CREATE TABLE cust_details_curr
(
 cust_id int,
 area_code varchar(5),
 cust_name varchar(20),
 cust_age int
 eff_date date
);

CREATE TABLE cust_details_hist
(
 cust_id int,
 area_code varchar(5),
 cust_name varchar(20),
 cust_age int
 eff_date date
) PARTITIONED BY LIST (eff_dt); -- Partitioned by List

table_name = "cust_details_curr"
table_name_hist = table_name + '_hist'

e = datetime.now()
eff_date = e.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
dttime = e.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

table_name_curr_part = table_name_part + '_' + str(dttime)

query_count = f"SELECT count(*) as cnt from {table_name} where area_code = '{area_code}'; "
query_date = f"SELECT distinct eff_date as eff_dt from {table_name} where area_code = '{area_code}';"

cur.execute(quey_date)
eff_date = cur.fetchone()[0]

query_crt = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name_curr_part} LIKE {table_name_part} INCLUDING DEFAULTS);"
query_ins_part = f"INSERT INTO {table_name_curr_part} SELECT * FROM {table_name} where area_code = '{area_code}' AND eff_dt = '{eff_date}';"
query_add_part = f"ALTER TABLE {table_name_part} ATTACH PARTITION {table_name_curr_part} FOR VALUES IN (DATE '{eff_date}') ;"
query_del = f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE area_code = '{area_code}';"
query_ins_curr = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (cust_id, area_code, cust_name, cust_age, eff_dt) VALUES %s"

cur.execute(....)
# Program trimmed in the interest of space
```

Can anyone please help me how to implement a workaround for the above requirements with multiple partition columns. How can I load data to an already existing partition ?

Happy to provide additional information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does it *need* to be partitioned by two columns? But if you really need to do that, you can use sub-partitioning. How exactly depends on why you need the partitioning (e.g. for fast removal of old data)

Comment: users want to query the hist table with either eff_date or the area_code or both. Partitioning on both the columns would ensure better query times, isn't it ? Any particular reason why multiple columns partitioning might not be required here ? Also, even if I partition by a single column, how do I insert data into the same partition created by an earlier instance of the job ?

Comment: Partitioning is not primarily a performance optimizations. It can only be used as such if all queries include the (complete) partition key. Otherwise it might actually make things slower. Proper indexing (maybe with partial indexes) gets you a long way

Comment: ok.. but even if i create a partition on a single column and dynamically create a partition (as shown in my example) as a separate table and then perform `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION..` , any idea how can I insert subsequent data to this already existing partition  (having the same value in part column) from another program instance?